# Javascript Docking Panel In Second Window

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to create a web app that has the ability to undock a panel and have it be put in a new window. I have used Kendo UI's docking panel, but it only allows you to do docking in the same window. Has anyone done anything like this? I would be open to any other frameworks as well.

Comment: You mean new browser window (not window widget), right? I'm afraid it's imposile using just Kendo UI itself.